# Continuous $f:$ open $\Omega \mapsto Y, Y$ (Banach) $\Rightarrow$ Inverse function is an open map

Tags: functional-analysis, open-map, inverse-function-theorem

I'm self-studying Cheney's book in Functional Analysis, and this is among the exercises (problem 3.4.5). I think I've proven the claim in the problem, but I guess I've made errors along the way or perhaps there is some easier way to show this:

Let $f: \Omega  \rightarrow Y $ be a continuously differentiable map, where $\Omega$ is an open set in a Banach space, and $Y$ is a normed linear space. Assume that $f'(x)$ is invertible for each $x\in \Omega $ and prove that $f(\Omega)$ is open.

Now, to remain faithful to the book's notation and pedagogical approach, I'm gonna bring the Inverse Function Theorem as stated there:

> Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable map from an open set $\Omega$
> in a Banach space into a normed linear space. If $x_0 \in \Omega$ and
> if $f'(x_0)$ is invertible, then there is a continuously
> differentiable function g defined on a neighborhood $N$ of $f(x_0)$
> such that $f(g(y)) = y, \forall y \in Y.$

---

So here is my attempt at the proof:

Let $x_0 \in \Omega \Rightarrow \exists N \subset Y$, s.t., $f(x_0) \in N$ and $f(f^{-1} (N)) =N,\, \, N$  open. (I denote $g$ by $f^{-1}.)$

$f$ is continuously differentiable $\Rightarrow $ it is indeed continuous, and as such: $f^{-1}(N)$ is open in $\Omega$.

Denoting $f^{-1}(N)$ by $V_{x_0}$, we get:

Now, because $f(x_0) \in N \Rightarrow x_0 \in f^{-1} (N)$. (Here is where I get into trouble, as I think I need **injectivity** to claim this. But that is not assumed in the problem description.)

$\forall x_0 \in \Omega, \exists V_{x_0} \subset \Omega , s.t. x_0 \in V_{x_0} \Rightarrow \Omega = \bigcup V_{x_0} \Rightarrow f(\Omega) = \bigcup f(V_{x_0})$ which is open as each $f(V_{x_0}) = N$.

I feel something's wrong in here, but I cannot pinpoint it. I'd appreciate any help correcting probable mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: Once you have, for a given $x_0\in\Omega$, the open set $N\subset Y$ containing $f(x_0)$  furnished by the Inverse Function Theorem, you are done. Indeed you then have $x_0\in N \subset f(\Omega)$. So $f(\Omega)$ is a neighbourhood of $f(x_0)$. But $x_0$ was arbitrary so $f(\Omega)$ is open. I think this is basically what you are trying to say.

Comment: Thanks. But all I get from the IFT is that $N \subset f(\Omega)$ is a neighborhood of $f(x_0)$. To conclude that $f(\Omega)$, itself, is open, I show that $f(\Omega) = \bigcup N.$ It is the procedure leading to that conclusion that seems shaky in my proof.

Comment: You don't need injectivity to justify that $x_0 \in f^{-1}(N)$ implies that $f(x_0) \in N$, because indeed both statements are equivalent.

Comment: What I'm saying in the proof is the reverse: that because $f(x_0) \in N$, then $x_0 \in f^{-1}(N).$ I still think I need injectivity for this one...

Comment: Ahh yes I read the reverse in your proof, but still I say that the implication is true without need of assuming injectivity because, as I stated above,  $x_0 \in f^{-1}(N)$ occurs if and only if $f(x_0) \in N$ (just remember that the set $f^{-1}(N)$ is by definition $\{x \in \Omega : f(x)\in N \}$).

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks. So the proof is fine then?

Comment: I haven't studied analysis-related topics in Banach spaces yet then I can't assure if your proof is correct or not, but I think it's fair how you express $f(\Omega)$ as a union of open sets :-) (btw @Neutrino if you want someone to notice your comment, you should tag them).

Comment: If you use thm 3.4.6 - Surjective Mapping theorem - it says that "f is locally surjective" - that is $N \subset f(\Omega)$

Comment: @EndreMoen Thanks, but note that the Surjective Mapping Theorem is about an $f$ from open set $\Omega$ to a *Banach* $Y$. Here, no assumption is made on $Y$–$Y$ is just an arbitrary NLS. That's why I think, to solve this problem I can only use the previous theorem 3.4.5 (Inverse Function Theorem I, also brought above) which is also about an arbitrary $Y$.